# HTML5 Doctype vs XMLNS attribute in HTML causes incorrect DOM parsing

Tags: php, html, simple-html-dom

I'm not entirely sure what's going on here but if I submit this HTML to the parser (a cut down example of a webpage being delivered by the Blogger platform):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html dir='ltr' lang='en' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml' xmlns:b='http://www.google.com/2005/gml/b' xmlns:data='http://www.google.com/2005/gml/data' xmlns:expr='http://www.google.com/2005/gml/expr'>
<head>
    <meta content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1' name='viewport'/>
    <title>Title</title>
    <meta content='text/html; charset=UTF-8' http-equiv='Content-Type'/>
</head>
<body>
    <p>Content</p>
</body>
</html>
```

it will fail to find the `<title>` tag text using:

```
$dom = HtmlDomParser::str_get_html($html);
$title = $dom->findOne('title')->text;
```

If I remove the `xmlns='http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml'` from the `<html>` tag then the parser will find the `<title>` text successfully.

Is this a mismatch between inferred HTML5 from the doctype vs the XMLNS attribute in the HTML tag, and therefore the parser doesn't understand, recognise, or is just baulking at the backslashes in the meta tags?

And, is there anything I can do about it when parsing the html, aside from running an `str_replace` on the `html` tag and removing the `xmlns` attribute before parsing the HTML.

Comment: Your question is a big confusing, because the string you say you're removing isn't in your example. Maybe just a mistake in editing it for inclusion? As to the question, I can't immediately see anything mentioning support for so-called "XHTML5" (HTML-as-XML) in that library, so it may just be getting generally confused by the use of namespaces (`xmlns`).

Comment: @IMSoP Thanks for pointing this out, this was a mistake on my part, as the example should include that string.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.